# How to implement a context manager for MySql either with MySQL connector or pyMySql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Trying to implement a context manager for a MySql connection I get an error message.

I have use MySql.connector module including the connection option to connect a database, and the pyMySql module, always getting the same result.

```
import pymysql

class MySQLConnector:
    def __init__(self, con_dict):
        self.cnx = None
        self.con_dict = con_dict

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cnx = pymysql.connect(**self.con_dict)
        return self.cnx

    def __exit__(self):
        self.cnx.close()

class ReceiveBroke(QDialog):           

    def __init__(self, db, config):    
        super().__init__()             
        with MySQLConnector(config) as 
            cur = self.cnx.cnx.cursor()
            qry = "SELECT * FROM horses
            cur.execute(qry)           
            result = cur.fetchall()    
            print(result)              
            self.setUI()               
            self.conTest()

    def conTest(self): 
        if self.cnx.ope
            print("y")
```

I hope to obtain a working context manager closing the database connection a finishing the with Block.
Result: Error Message. Always after executing the last line within the "with" block :"TypeError **exit** takes one positional argument but four were given" at which time the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

hope you found the error already. If not, I think the error message is quite clear:

```
TypeError exit takes one positional argument but four were given
```

`__exit__` function needs 4 arguments: self, type, value, traceback. These last 3 relate to any exception that may happen in the `with` block.